# React fetching data from XML file

Tags: xml, reactjs

I have the following inside my HTML file:

```
<script type="text/babel">

    var App = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'data.xml',
              dataType: 'xml',
              cache: false,
              success: function(data) {
                data = xmlToJson(data);
                console.log(data);
              }.bind(this)
            });
            return (<p>data</p>);
        }
    }); 


    ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );
</script>
```

however the console is throwing the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/alessandro.santese/Documents/Documents/Documents/Alessandro-UI/PROJECTS/Firefly/task_2/data.xml?_=1468834003361. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ajax requests need a server to fetch the file from, they can't fetch a file from the your localStorage. Just run your application on a server. You can use any server for this purpose example, `tomcat`, or `http-server`.

If you are on a `linux` or `max-os` or an os that has python installed in it you can go to your project directory and run a server from there using

```
python –m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

or alternatively you can use nodejs http-server. Install it with command `npm install -g http-server` and run it from you project directory as `http-server ./`

I hope this solution helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a cross origin request , you should run a http server locally and then request your data.xml file

```
npm install -g http-server
```